# Aceite termos de uso

Tags: ip

O que deve ser capturado do usuário quando o mesmo clica em aceitar os termos de uso do meu sistema, app ou site?

Normalmente ouço pessoas dizendo que deve ser capturado o IP e Data Hora, mais juridicamente esses dados são válidos para provar que o usuário realmente concordou com os termos?

Comment: Vou usar o Facebook por exemplo, para se cadastrar precisa concordar, ou seja todos os 1B de usuários cadastrados aceitaram o termo, pois não é possível cadastrar sem aceitar os termos e as implicações legais que ele contém, entende?

Comment: No caso não seria necessário guardar esses dados, pois esses dados (hora, ip etc) não poderiam ser ligado a uma pessoa em sí (no caso um CPF/CNPJ brasileiro) poderiam ser simplesmente de um usuário fake/fantasma. Agora se você exigir no seu site uma identificação real, um cpf no caso, aí a história muda....

Comment: Acho que é fora do escopo do site dizer se é "juridicamente válido". Imagino que o único que você pode recolher são as informações públicas (IP e tal) e as voluntárias. Acho que dá pra orientar sua pergunta mais pro lado *programador* que pro lado *advogado*. Fiz [esta pesquisa](http://law.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q="terms%20of%20service"%20is%3aq) no Law.SE e achei esta interessante: [What is the point of website Terms and Conditions?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1863)

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma questão que pode dar margem para outras interpretações. Visto que o meio jurídico não tem muito bem definido o que é válido ou não.

Ou seja, a validade do consentimento dos usuários aos Termos de Uso e Políticas de Privacidade de aplicações de internet independe da simples redação de referidos documentos.

Um exemplo é o uso de checkboxes indicando aceitação aos Termos de Uso ou Políticas de Privacidade quando do cadastro de novo usuário. Por depender o consentimento de uma ação positiva do usuário, é imprescindível que este efetivamente clique na respectiva **checkbox** indicando sua concordância. Caso referida **checkbox** já se encontre preenchida no formulário de cadastro, não haverá uma ação do usuário para aceitação, podendo o consentimento vir a ser invalidado em caso de disputa.

Para garantir a validade e eficácia de Termos de Uso e Políticas de Privacidade, advogados devem atuar em conjunto com seus clientes, afim de entender o modelo de negócio proposto e sugerir soluções práticas.